# Saber quando o computador foi Ligado / Desligado / Interrompido

Tags: c#, windows, log, aplicação-desktop

Eu queria saber quando o computador foi ligado, desligado ou foi interrompido.
Se eu liguei o meu computador, a partir da data de hoje, então eu quero saber o horário e a data que foi ligado. No desligamento a mesma coisa, se eu desliguei o computador "normalmente", a partir da data de hoje, então capturar a data e a hora. Se foi interrompido ou forçado por exemplo, desligado fora da tomada ou faltou energia, então capturar todos esses dados.

Soube que a referência: [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader](http://System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader) Contém um conjunto de Classes para obter os logs de eventos do sistema, mas não sei como usar.

Depois de muita pesquisa, acabei achando o código que gera o evento de ínicio e desligamento do sistema abaixo.

```
if (EventLog.Exists("System"))
{
    var log = new EventLog("System", Environment.MachineName, "EventLog");

    var entries = new EventLogEntry[log.Entries.Count];
    log.Entries.CopyTo(entries, 0);

    var startupTimes = entries.Where(x => x.InstanceId == 2147489653).Select(x => x.TimeGenerated);
    var shutdownTimes = entries.Where(x => x.InstanceId == 2147489654).Select(x => x.TimeGenerated);
}
```

Na hora de puxar o **horário** e a **data** que está nas duas variáveis acima, aparece o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A hora e a data estão praticamente erradas. Estou em **2018** e na data das duas variáveis estou em **0001**. Se a data está errada então quer dizer que o horário também está. E também, as duas variáveis estão com o mesmo valor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema mencionado na pergunta em relação à data apresentada, é porque você estava recebendo uma lista e não estava consultando o valor referente a um elemento dela, apenas o default de sua estrutura.

Eu utilizaria um Helper para facilitar o mapeamento e consulta dos eventos que você pretende, abaixo segue um modelo básico (utilizando o seu próprio código) e um exemplo de implementação. Dessa forma você terá total liberdade para trabalhar com os `EventLogEntry` do jeito que for mais útil.

ConsultaEventosHelper

```
public static class ConsultaEventosHelper
{
    private const long inicializacao = 2147489653;
    private const long desligamento = 2147484722;
    private const long reinicializacao = 2147489654;

    public static List<EventLogEntry> Inicializacao { get { return ConsultaOcorrencias(inicializacao); } }
    public static List<EventLogEntry> Desligamento { get { return ConsultaOcorrencias(desligamento); } }
    public static List<EventLogEntry> Reinicializacao { get { return ConsultaOcorrencias(reinicializacao); } }

    public static List<EventLogEntry> ConsultaOcorrencias(long instanceId)
    {
        List<EventLogEntry> resultado = new List<EventLogEntry>();

        if (EventLog.Exists("System"))
        {
            using (var log = new EventLog("System", Environment.MachineName, "EventLog"))
            {
                var entries = new EventLogEntry[log.Entries.Count];
                log.Entries.CopyTo(entries, 0);
                resultado = entries.Where(x => x.InstanceId == instanceId).ToList();
            }
        }

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{


    var ultimaInicializacao = ConsultaEventosHelper.Inicializacao.LastOrDefault();
    var ultimoDesligamento = ConsultaEventosHelper.Desligamento.LastOrDefault(); 
    var ultimaReinicializacao = ConsultaEventosHelper.Reinicializacao.LastOrDefault(); 

    Console.WriteLine("Última Incializacao: {0} - {1}", ultimaInicializacao.TimeGenerated, ultimaInicializacao.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Última Reinicializacao: {0} - {1}", ultimaReinicializacao.TimeGenerated, ultimaReinicializacao.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Último Desligamento: {0} - {1}", ultimoDesligamento.TimeGenerated, ultimoDesligamento.Message);


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando uma abordagem diferente para obter o [TimeGenerated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.timegenerated(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Observação: Geralmente, há um atraso entre o horário em que um evento é gerado e o horário em que ele é registrado. É mais importante saber quando o evento foi gerado, a menos que você queira ver se há um atraso significativo no registro. Isso pode acontecer se seus arquivos de log estiverem em um servidor diferente e você estiver com um gargalo. Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.timegenerated(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EventLog ev = new EventLog("System", Environment.MachineName);

            if (ev.Entries.Count <= 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Nenhum log de eventos no log :" + "System");

            for (int i = ev.Entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                EventLogEntry CurrentEntry = ev.Entries[i];

                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan ts = dt.Subtract( CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated);
                int hours = (ts.Days * 24) + ts.Hours;

                if (CurrentEntry.Source.ToUpper() == "USER32")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tempo gerado:" + CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated);
                    Console.WriteLine("Horas atrás:" + hours);
                    Console.WriteLine("Event Id : " + CurrentEntry.InstanceId);
                    Console.WriteLine("Entry Type : " + CurrentEntry.EntryType.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Mensagem :  " + CurrentEntry.Message + "\n");
                }
            }
            ev.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Fonte do código [aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185716/4312593)

Answer (score 0):

Consegue controlar pelo menos o `logoff` e o `shutdown` da seguinte forma:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MyApp
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEvents_SessionEnding;
    }

    private void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.Logoff)
        {
            // colocar aqui o código para logoff
        }
        else
        {
            // colocar aqui o código para shutdown
        }
    }
}
```